# configure vscode react native auto-imports without ts errors

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I'm working on a `React Native` project using `Javascript`.

I want vscode to display the quick fix imports suggestion like this one:

[image]

The problem is that it also displays `typescript` errors, like this one:

[image]

Here is my `jsconfig.json` file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES6",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "checkJs": true,
  "jsx": "react-native"
},
"exclude": ["node_modules"],
"include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

I've realised that if I comment out `"checkJs": true,` the errors are gone but then the import suggestions doesn't appear anymore.

Here my `settings.json`:

```
{
"workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
"editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"editor.fontSize": 13,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"git.autofetch": true,
"git.confirmSync": false,
"[javascript]": {
    
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
"typescript.validate.enable": false,
"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": true,
}
```

I've already read many posts and played around disabling `typescript` and `javascript` validation `"typescript.validate.enable": false,` but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? I'm coming from webstorm so I'm not really used to vscode.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need a config for auto imports, but you could install the Auto import snippet from VSC snippets,
here is the [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) try it.

also, the error from your typescript is not related to the auto import, it is a typescript error, your touchableOpacity still missing some props.

Comment: I've tried that VScode extension but it doesn't work. Maybe I haven't explained myself 100% clear, but I'm not using typescript, that's why I want to get rid of the typescript validation errors

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create `jsconfig.json` and type in:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "checkJs": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```